# Spring Boot - Angular CORS issue while redirecting to Keycloak Login Page

Tags: angular, spring, spring-security, cors, keycloak

I have a simple Rest API written in Spring Boot. I have implemented OAuth2 with Keycloak. I have a UI written in Angular.

My expectation is, when I hit the API url from the Angular Page (say a Button click), I should be redirected to Keycloak Login Page. But when I try to access the API from Angular Application, I am getting the below error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost:8080/realms/CloudBrokerRealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=cloud-broker-client2&scope=openid&state=pgUtz5IX5ONC3NQ6o9v3IbPnB2DB9rUr3O40tuRxGHY%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8085/login/oauth2/code/keycloak&nonce=CjpTbFvhBqxD0Rz4SQk49rT-wsB3C279NlGHDExlh6M'
> (**redirected from 'http://localhost:8085/scheduler/read'**) from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

When I hit the API http://localhost:8085/scheduler/read by clicking a Button from Angular, It is trying to redirect to Keycloak Login page but due to CORS error, Login page of Keycloak is not coming.

For accessing the backend API http://localhost:8085/scheduler/read , I have done the CORS configuration in Spring Boot and no CORS issues with this API when I directly accessing this API url from browser and Keycloak Login Page is coming. But the issue is occurring when from Angular Application running in http://localhost:4200 , we are trying to hit the API and it is trying to redirect to Keycloak Login Page http://localhost:8080/realms/CloudBrokerRealm/protoco.......

I have added Web Origins in Keycloak under the client but still CORS issue persists. Is there any way to bypass the CORS issue or can we disable the CORS in Keycloak. I am running Keycloak as a docker container.

**Spring Boot application.properties :**

```
server.port=8085

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=cloud-broker-client2
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.scope=openid

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8080/realms/CloudBrokerRealm
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-name-attribute=preferred_username


spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8080/realms/CloudBrokerRealm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you configured your REST API as client (using `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and oauth2Login).

This is wrong. REST APIs are resource-server and must be configured with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`. If you don't know how, follow [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials).

To ease OAurh2 handling on the client, use an OIDC client library. My favorite for Angular is [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client).

Once both points above are solved, only http://localhost:4200 will be necessary as allowed origin on both Keycloak and your REST API.

Comment: Yes, I am using spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client for redirecting to Keycloak Login Page from Angular UI. Do I need to use spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server for redirecting to Keycloak Login Page from Angular UI instead of spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client? 

Second question is, do I need to use angular-auth-oidc-client & spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server both for  redirecting to Keycloak Login Page from Angular UI ?

Comment: Technically, you are using spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client to redirect from your API (not Angular client) to authorization server because your client is sending an unauthorized request (no authorization header) to a secured resource. An OAuth2 client should send an access-token with requests to protected resources. Follow spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client getting started guide for user authentication and requests authorization.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Sure I will go through the docs you suggested. Just last one question, as you said, I am using spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client to redirect from my API (not Angular client) to authorization server as initially there is no access token. So is it wrong way to do it? Should I redirect from Angular Client instead of Rest API?

I have edited my original questions to add the spring boot application.properties configuration.

Comment: Yes, this is wrong. OAuth2 request to secured resource should have an access token already. Angular client lib will do all the OAuth2 grunt job for you (redirection to login, exchange of authorization code for tokens, token silent refresh, interceptor to add access-token, route guards with auto-login, etc.), just try it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information and suggestions. I will try it for sure. Appreciate your time.